# Exception in using the application containing struts 2 spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring

I am creating a application which is using struts2 spring and hibernate .the Exception which i am getting is context initialization failed

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory'
  defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/sampleContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
  Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; 
  nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

I have all the pertinent jar in my lib

Comment: post the whole stacktrace

Comment: I resolved the problem by using weblogic.xml alongwith other configuration files.:)